# Cannot correctly stop thread pool

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Here is my `ThreadPool` implementation. I've tried it in simple function `main` and cannot stop it correctly, destructor is called before threads start and whole program finish in the deadlock (on `t.join()`) because condition variable has been called before thread reached `wait` function.

Any ideas how to fix it? Or there is a better way to implement it?

`ThreadPool.cpp`

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>


namespace Concurrency {
template <typename RetType>
class StandardThreadPool : public ThreadPool<RetType> {
private:
  typedef std::function<RetType()> taskType;
  ThreadSafeQueue<std::packaged_task<RetType()>> queue;

  std::mutex queueMutex;
  std::condition_variable queueCondition;

  std::vector<std::thread> poolThreads;
  std::atomic<bool> stopThreadsFlag{false};

  void threadWork() {
    std::cout << "thread:" << std::this_thread::get_id() << " started\n";
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queueMutex);
    while (true) {
      queueCondition.wait(lock);

      if (stopThreadsFlag.load())
        break;

      auto task = queue.Pop();

      if (task)
        (*task)();
    }
    std::cout << "thread:" << std::this_thread::get_id() << " finished\n";
  }

  void initThreadPool() {
    poolThreads.resize(StandardThreadPool<RetType>::maxThreads);
  }

  void startThreads() {
    for (int i = 0; i < StandardThreadPool<RetType>::maxThreads; i++) {
      poolThreads[i] =
          std::thread(&StandardThreadPool<RetType>::threadWork, this);
    }
  }

  void terminateThreads() {
    stopThreadsFlag.store(true);
    queueCondition.notify_all();

    for (auto &t : poolThreads) {
      t.join();
    }
  }

public:
  StandardThreadPool(int maxThreads) : ThreadPool<RetType>(maxThreads) {
    initThreadPool();
    startThreads();
  }

  std::future<RetType> virtual Push(taskType &&task) override {
    std::packaged_task<RetType()> pt = std::packaged_task<RetType()>(task);
    auto future = pt.get_future();
    queue.Push(std::move(pt));

    queueCondition.notify_one();
    return future;
  }

  ~StandardThreadPool<RetType>() {
    std::cout << "destructor called\n";
    terminateThreads(); }
};

} // namespace Concurrency
```

```
namespace Concurrency {
template <typename T> class ThreadSafeQueue {
private:
  struct node {
    std::shared_ptr<T> data;
    std::unique_ptr<node> next;
  };

  std::mutex headMutex;
  std::mutex tailMutex;

  std::unique_ptr<node> head;
  node *tail;

  node *getTail() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(tailMutex);
    return tail;
  }

  std::unique_ptr<node> popHead() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(headMutex);

    if (head.get() == getTail())
      return nullptr;

    std::unique_ptr<node> oldHead(std::move(head));
    head = std::move(oldHead->next);

    return oldHead;
  }

public:
  ThreadSafeQueue() : head(new node), tail(head.get()) {}

  std::shared_ptr<T> Pop() {
    auto oldHead = popHead();

    return oldHead ? oldHead->data : nullptr;
  }

  void Push(T &newValue) {
    auto newData = std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<T>(newValue));
    std::unique_ptr<node> pNew(new node);

    auto newTail = pNew.get();

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(tailMutex);
    tail->data = newData;
    tail->next = std::move(pNew);

    tail = newTail;
  }

  void Push(T &&newValue) {
    auto newData = std::make_shared<T>(std::move(newValue));
    std::unique_ptr<node> pNew(new node);

    auto newTail = pNew.get();

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(tailMutex);
    tail->data = newData;
    tail->next = std::move(pNew);

    tail = newTail;
  }

  ThreadSafeQueue(const ThreadSafeQueue &) = delete;
  ThreadSafeQueue &operator=(const ThreadSafeQueue &) = delete;
};
} // namespace Concurrency
```

```
#include <functional>
#include <future>

namespace Concurrency {

template <typename RetType> class ThreadPool {
public:
  int maxThreads;

public:
  typedef std::function<RetType()> taskType;
  ThreadPool(int maxThreads):maxThreads(maxThreads){}

  virtual std::future<RetType> Push(taskType &&newTask) = 0;

  ThreadPool(const ThreadPool &) = delete;
  ThreadPool(const ThreadPool &&) = delete;
};
} // namespace Concurrency
```

`main.cpp`

```
int main() {
  Concurrency::StandardThreadPool<int> th(1);
  auto fun = []() {
    std::cout << "function running\n";
    return 2;
  };

  th.Push(fun);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `ThreadSafeQueue` -- use a `std::deque`.  Stop writing manual linked lists.  Also, the mutex and the condition variable go *inside* the thread-safe queue, not outside.  And definitely not both inside and outside!  You are using condition variables wrong, they are a triple of (state) (mutex) and (cv) that need to be integrated together.  They are a low level building block; almost every use you did of the condition variable is incorrect.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Can you shortly explain why linked list is a bad idea in this example?

Comment: Sure.  You are writing a linked list.  Not only is that error prone, you won't write as good a one as std::list; and even std::list is 999/1000 times worse than std::deque (which is 9/10 times worse than a std::vector, but this is 1 of the 10 times when deque is right).  Don't do manual pointer manipulation when you don't have to, and there is nothing your linked list does that a deque doesn't do better here.

Comment: I mean, you are writing concurrency code.  Why would you pile up all of your concurrency complication with a "I know, I'll roll a linked list here, I'm sure the bugs won't compound".  :p  If you need a custom linked list, you should write that separately, unit test the heck out of it, and use it in production for a few years ... then make it concurrent.  Concurrency is *hard*, don't do it with two hands and 3 legs tied behind your back.

Comment: your main() functions does `th.Push(fun);` and then it ends (calling any relevant destructors within the mainI() function). You need to implement some sort of waiting until you want your threadpool to stop/terminate, and not exit the function (main() in your example) that created the threadpool until it's stopped/terminated.

Comment: @nos i thought that joining all threads in destructor is a good solution for that, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a correct threadsafe queue.

```
template<class T>
struct threadsafe_queue {
  [[nodiscard]] std::optional<T> pop() {
    auto l = lock();
    cv.wait(l, [&]{ return is_aborted() || !data.empty(); });
    if (is_aborted())
      return {};
    auto r = std::move(data.front());
    data.pop_front();
    cv.notify_all(); // for wait_until_empty
    return r; // might need std::move here, depending on compiler version
  }
  bool push(T t) {
    auto l = lock();
    if (is_aborted()) return false;
    data.push_back(std::move(t));
    cv.notify_one();
    return true;
  }
  void set_abort_flag() {
    auto l = lock(); // still need this
    aborted = true;
    data.clear();
    cv.notify_all();
  }
  [[nodiscard]] bool is_aborted() const { return aborted; }
  void wait_until_empty() {
    auto l = lock();
    cv.wait(l, [&]{ return data.empty(); });
  }
private:
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock() {
    return std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m);
  }
  std::condition_variable cv;
  std::mutex m;
  std::atomic<bool> aborted{false};
  std::deque<T> data;
};
```

this handles abort and the like internally.

Our threadpool then becomes:

```
struct threadpool {
  explicit threadpool(std::size_t count)
  {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
      threads.emplace_back([&]{
        // abort handled by empty pop:
        while( auto f = queue.pop() ) {
          (*f)();
        }
      });
    }
  }
  void set_abort_flag() {
    queue.set_abort_flag();
  }
  [[nodiscard]] bool is_aborted() const {
    return queue.is_aborted();
  }
  ~threadpool() {
    queue.wait_until_empty();
    queue.set_abort_flag(); // get threads to leave the queue
    for (std::thread& t:threads)
      t.join();
  }
  template<class F,
    class R=typename std::result_of<F()>::type
  >
  std::future<R> push_task( F f ) {
    std::packaged_task<R()> task( std::move(f) );
    auto ret = task.get_future();
    if (queue.push( std::packaged_task<void()>(std::move(task)) )) // wait, this works?  Yes it does.
      return ret;
    else
      return {}; // cannot push, already aborted
  }
private:
  // yes, void.  This is evil but it works
  threadsafe_queue<std::packaged_task<void()>> queue;
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
};
```

in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) you can swap the `std::optional` for `std::unique_ptr`.  More runtime overhead.

The trick here is that a `std::packaged_task<void()>` can store a `std::packaged_task<R()>`.  And we don't need the return value in the queue.  So one thread pool can handle any number of different return values in tasks -- it doesn't care.

I only join the threads on `thread_pool` destruction.  I could do it after an abort as well.

Destroying a `thread_pool` waits until all tasks are complete.  Note that aborting a thread_pool may not abort tasks in progress.  One thing that you probably want to add is the option of passing an abort API/flag to the tasks, so they can abort early if asked.

Getting this industrial scale is hard, because ideally all blocking in a task would also pay attention to the abort possibility.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/ajrhabeoP).

You could add a 2nd `cv` to notify after pops, which only `wait_until_empty` waits on.  That might safe you some spurious wakeups.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate the effort :D